# Return value's type like type in parameter

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Can I create a method so that it returns the value of the type that I specify in parameters?
For example:

```
int i = Settings.Get("count", typeof(int));
string s = Settings.Get("count", typeof(string));
Guid g = Settings.Get("count", typeof(Guid));
```

Comment: how about return object instead?

Answer (score 4):

```
public T Get<T> (string value)
{
     //read setting and cast


     //or if you have Setting.Get implementation
     return (T)Settings.Get("count", typeof(T));
}
```

now you can

```
int i = Get<int>("count");
string i = Get<string>("count");
Guid i = Get<Guid>("count");
```

Comment: What's the advantage of writing `Get<int>("count")` everywhere instead of, say, `GetInt("count")`?

Comment: @dtb how else can you specufy returning type?

Comment: `GetInt` returns `int`, `GetString` returns `string`, etc.?

Comment: @dtb so you need one method per possible returning type?

Comment: @dtb and why wouldn't you use generics? In your case, you would have to create a separate method for each case.

Comment: You need a different implementation for each `T` in your `Get<T>` as well. And it doesn't work for all `T`, just a few select. So providing one method for each type that is actually supported would prevent bugs.

Comment: `You need a different implementation for each T` - sorry, but that's simply not the case

Comment: @dtb no you don't. You just cast the value to T and return it.

Comment: Where do you get the value from? If you have a method `Settings.Get(String, Type)` then, sure, you only have to cast the return value to `T`. But then this method needs a different implementation for each `Type` that's passed to it.

Comment: And my original question still holds: What's the advantage of writing `Get<int>("count")` everywhere instead of `GetInt("count")`? There may be differences between how this is implemented, but what's the advantage for the caller? `Get<int>("count")` has a disadvantage for the caller, namely that a wrong type is detected only at run-time although it could be detected at compile-time.

Comment: @dtb you can use generic restrictions. This is more flexible solution. Suposse you need to write `StudentRepository` and `ClassRepository`, instead of single implementation `Repository<T> where T : EntityBase`. I this is a common pattern in java world, but generics is different type of **API**, which has lots of benefits

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by making the method generic:

```
Settings.Get<T>(string name);
```

Inside the Get method you need to load the value and then cast it to `T`:

```
public T Get<T>(string value)
{
    object o = 1; // read setting;
    return (T)o;
}
```

And then call it:

```
int i = Get<int>("count");
```

Answer (score 2):

why don't you try generics like this

```
   public T Get<T>(string value)
   {
     // do your stuff and cast the value
   }
```

where T is type